# How can I write with proper alignment in latex?

Tags: formatting, cv

I was trying to write a CV on latex. The format looks like the below picture [image: Expected outcome]
I've tried doing that using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\hline
\begin{paragraph}{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}} 
\mbox{}

{Sep 2020 — Present} \hfill{\bf Project Manager, X Consultancy} \hfill 
{Groningen} \\ 
{\mbox{}} \hfill {Have gone through certain projects. Lorem ipsum, or 
lipsum as it is 
sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web 
designs. The passage 
is attributed to an unknown} \hfill {}

\end{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

I've got the following outcome.[image: My Result]

Can anyone please help me with how can I get the expected outcome and align the middle column perfectly with the bullets?

Comment: Unrelated: With modern LaTeX you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as that is the default.

Comment: Also, `\hline` is meant for usage inside the `tabular` environment. To get a page-spanning rule you should use `\hrule`.

Comment: And `\paragraph` isn't an environment, but a macro, and  using `\textbf` in its argument is semantically wrong. Such font settings should be applied by `\paragraph` itself (and by default are), not manually in its argument.

Comment: And using font switches like `\bf` is discontinued in LaTeX since many years, you should use `\bfseries` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to create your own cv style starting from `article`, I'd suggest using the `geometry` package and creating a big left margin, and then use macros that print into said margin.

The following could get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\leftcolwidth
\setlength\leftcolwidth{3cm}
\newlength\leftcolsep
\setlength\leftcolsep{5mm}

\usepackage
  [left=\dimexpr\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep+3.5cm\relax,right=3.5cm]
  {geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pagerule
  {%
    \par
    \smallskip
    \noindent
    \kern-\leftcolwidth
    \kern-\leftcolsep
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep}{.4pt}%
    \par
    \smallskip
    \@doendpe % suppress indent of the next line if no blank line is following
  }

\newcommand*\entry[3]
  {%
    \par
    \noindent
    \llap{\makebox[\leftcolwidth][l]{#1}\kern\leftcolsep}%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill
    \makebox{#3}%
    \par
    \medskip % vertical space below the entries
    \@afterindentfalse % don't indent the first paragraph
    \@afterheading     % don't allow page breaks
  }

% change the formatting of paragraph
\renewcommand\paragraph
  {%a
    \@startsection
      {paragraph}{4}%
      {-\dimexpr\leftcolwidth+\leftcolsep\relax}% move it into the margin
      {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}% vertical space before the heading
      {1em}% add a bit of vertical space after the heading
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% set the wanted font
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagerule

\paragraph{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} 
\entry{Sep 2020 -- Present}{Project Manager, X Consultancy}{Groningen}
\begin{itemize}
  \item
    Have gone through certain projects. Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is
    sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web
    designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer.

Comment: But I need to reduce the top margin. I am not getting the line of code for that.

Comment: @khair In the options of the `geometry` package add `top=<length>`.

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanks a lot.